# Get full name from a relation and show in view

Tags: php, yii2

This is the relation I have in my model

```
 public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
    }

     public function getTaskCreatedBy()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'taskCreatedBy']);
    }
```

And now i want to use `taskcreatedby` and get `fullname` of user which i have done like this:

```
 Created By:<?php echo $model->taskCreatedBy->fullname?>
```

But, I am getting error saying :Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: show  your related  controller action

Comment: verify if you have an associated record for the `$model` you are trying to call the relation with.

Comment: Yes there is association between them

Comment: Try print_r($model->taskCreatedBy) to make sure that there is an object here and put the result here pls :)

Comment: I tried it and it prints id

Comment: my controlller action: 
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    public function actionUserview($id)
    {
        return $this->render('userview', [
            'model' => User::findOne($id),
        ]); }

Comment: Thank You all for your concern I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

check the real column name  could be that your db colum name is not taskCreatedBy   but  somethings different  eg:  (or others column name)

```
public function getTaskCreatedBy()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'task_created_by']);
}
```

Comment: I bit this is the case, i.e miss column name.

Comment: yeah thats the case

Comment: @RajanChaulagain   uppercase and lowercase  case match ??  data type is the same ??

Comment: then firts check if $model is null  using var_dump($model)  then check if $model->taskCreatedBy is null  using  var_dump($model->taskCreatedBy)  and let me know

Comment: Thank You  for your concern I have solved the problem.

Comment: can you tell me what was the  issue ??

Answer (score 0):

So you have 2 relations connecting to this model/table. 
1. A User table connects to the user_id field/database column in this model.
2. A TaskCreatedBy table connects to the taskCreatedBy field in this model.

What is this model's table's name? Found in your tableName function.

```
public static function tableName()
    {
        return '???????????????';
    }
```

Understanding the below code:

```
['id' => 'taskCreatedBy']
```

can be summarised as follows:

['fieldname called 'id'  in foreign model table called TaskCreatedBy'  => 'fieldname called taskCreatedBy in current model table' ie. the name of the foreign key field/database column that is in your current model table ...the name of this model/file/table which you have not given us]

Verify that 'taskCreatedBy' , as in the above snippet of code, is the actual name of the field in your current  model table ie. the table belonging to the file that the above code is in.

## 1

I would simplify your table names to avoid getting uppercase and lowercase issues when having to type your relation code

```
<?php echo $model->taskCreatedBy->fullname?>
```

## 2

and also not use a field/database column  like taskCreatedBy which is very similar to the table name TaskCreatedBy. My suggestion is that you rename your field taskCreatedBy in your table TaskCreatedBy  to taskcreatedby_id.

## 3

In the above snippet of code

```
['id' => 'taskCreatedBy']
```

taskCreatedBy should be in lowercase and correspond to the actual field/database column name preferably taskcreatedby_id that exists in your current model/table.

Comment: Thank You again for your concern I have solved the problem.

Comment: No probs Rajan.